# Rename Site collection after re creating it once after deletion :SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, site-collection

Old Site Collection name = ABC

delete the site collection

Create a new Site COllection with same name = ABC

but on UI the title of site collection shows ABC-2

I have tried updating the title through UI (under site settings, Look and feel) and through powershell too.

Is there any other method?

**EDIT**

I am able to change the title through UI, just add a space or two in the title. But then when I check the permissions of site, there still the ABC-2 Memebers, ABC-2 Owners shows up.

Comment: Are you really talking about deleting a Site **Collection** or just a **Site (Web)**? You mentioned "*-2" user groups. Sounds to me like you've deleted and re-created a Subsite within a Site Collection. Try to remove the deleted Subsite from the recycle bin, before you create a new Subsite with the same name.

Comment: It is a site collection.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint adds the number because the name still exists because of the site collection not being completely removed from the content database. If you would try to create a third, it would be called ABC-3 and so on.

Changing the title, the site collection will still be named ABC-2 internally.

When you remove a site collection from the UI, the site collection does still exist but is marked for deletion for 30 days until it is deleted permanently.

The only way to remove the deleted site collection is to through PowerShell.

This step can be avoided by deleting the site collection itself using PowerShell from the first time.

You can type [Get-SPDeletedSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286316.aspx) to see what site collections that are marked for deletion.

Then you can use [Remove-SPDeletedSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286317.aspx) to remove the site from the database and thus be able to create a new site collection with the same name.

If you wanna delete all the site collection at the same time you can pipe the 2 cmdlts together: `Get-SPDeletedSite | Remove-SPDeletedSite`

If you only wanna remove a single site, type `Remove-SPDeletedSite -Identity "http://farm/sites/sitecollToRemove"`

Comment: tried the method above. With Get-SPDeletedSite i got 2 site collections names. then I executed  "Get-SPDeletedSite | Remove-SPDeletedSite" After renamed the site collection's title through UI, still same results. It comes with ABC - 2. Again Executing Get-SPDeletedSite shows no results.Also tried renaming by powershell

Comment: Changing the title form the UI is not enough. You could try to use the set-spsite cmd but i think that you should remove all fault site collections and begin from the start when you have removed all of them with PowerShell.

Comment: will it work for sp2010 too? I checked the command set-spsite. But my site url is something like http://"servername":8080/. I dont want the url to be changed just site collection title.